# Updating a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to update a value in a table, but I can't.

The table `foo` has different columns; primary key is the column `mail`, and I want to update the value in the column `cellphone`.

The query is:

```
UPDATE foo
SET cellphone = "+391234556789"
WHERE mail = "name.surname@gmail.com";
```

The error I get tells me that the column `"name.surname@gmail.com"` doesn't exists.

Both `mail` and `cellphone` are `CHARVAR`.

Comment: Do not use double quotes use single quotes. In postgresql any value enclosed in double quotes referred as column_name.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I was a bit rusty on PostgreSQL.
`UPDATE foo
SET cellphone = '+391234556789'
WHERE mail = 'name.surname@gmail.com';`
works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments of the question, the error was in using double quotes.

The following code in fact, works.

```
UPDATE foo
SET cellphone = '+391234556789'
WHERE mail = name.surname@gmail.com';
```